# How to get a value of gui element in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I'm trying to get a value of an element from dispatcher. However I can't wrap my head around how to pass it later in the code. I want to pass progress to the testbox about what was done.

I get the value whenever I just use `ProductId.Text` in the main thread.

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ProductId.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    string productId = ProductId.Text;});
                Console.WriteLine($"Creating game {productId}");
            });
```

I just want to pass the variable productId later in the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use a `Task` if you want to access a UI element? You'll have to get back to the UI thread to do so. That's what `Dispatcher.Invoke` does. You could remove all this code and simply write `string productId = ProductId.Text;`

Comment: That said, you should *not* modify the UI nor try to read anything from it directly. WPF offers data binding which makes it easy to connect UI elements with data without hard-coding or threading issues. WPF itself would store any changes to `ProductID` to the property it was bound to

Comment: What are you trying to do? Whatever it is, it doesn't require accessing the UI from a background thread.

Comment: I am currently running some operations via ssh when I click a button, but I wanted to return the progress of the operations back to the testbox, so the user does know what is going on, because right now when I click the button the whole gui freezes for the time of operations.

Comment: That's not what you posted in this code though. In any case, MVVM and data binding still work - modifying a data bound property, even from a background thread, will cause the UI to update itself properly. Another option is to use the `Progress<T>` class to send progress messages from the background task/thread to the UI thread.

Comment: Yeah, because whole operations take hundreds of lines, so I didn't want to make it unreadable. Through databinding I could get the values of UI elements to the background thread?

Comment: you removed the important code though and left the noise. Besides, you just said you want to *write* to the UI, not read from the UI. You should read from the UI *before* starting the background thread. Put all your code in a separate method that accepts whatever it needs as parameters instead of trying to grab them from the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it seems there's a long-running background process that needs to post updates to the UI.

This is easy to do using the [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8) class and the [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface. This is described in [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/). The [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8) can raise an event or call an `Action<T>` callback on the thread it was created on. The [IProgress.Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.8) method allows other threads to send messages to the Progress

Copying from the article's example, this method processes images in a background thread. Each time it wants to report progress, it calls `progress.Report(message);`

```
async Task<int> UploadPicturesAsync(List<Image> imageList, IProgress<string> progress)
{
        int totalCount = imageList.Count;
        int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
        {
            foreach (var image in imageList)
            {
                //await the processing and uploading logic here
                int processed = await UploadAndProcessAsync(image);
                if (progress != null)
                {
                    var message=$"{(tempCount * 100 / totalCount)}";
                    progress.Report(message);
                }
                tempCount++;
            }

            return tempCount;
        });
        return processCount;
}
```

All that's needed is to create a new Progress instance in the UI thread before starting the asynchronous method :

```
void ReportProgress(string message)
{
    //Update the UI to reflect the progress value that is passed back.
    txtProgress.Text=message;
}

private async void Start_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //construct Progress<T>, passing ReportProgress as the Action<T> 
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);

    //load the image list *before* starting the background worker
    var folder=txtPath.Text;
    var imageList=LoadImages(folder);
   //call async method
    int uploads=await UploadPicturesAsync(imageList, progressIndicator);
}
```

**Reading from the UI**

Another important thing is that `UploadPicturesAsync` *doesn't* try to read its input from the UI element, whichever it may be. It accepts the input it needs, the list of images, as a parameter. This makes it easier to run in the background, easier to test and a lot easier to modify.

For example, instead of reading from a text box, the code could be modified to display a Folder Browser dialog.